# Google Safebrowsing checking JavaScript

Tags: javascript, safe-browsing

Is it possible to extract a website safebrowsing info by javascript?  This can be with Google Safe Browsing API, is there any code, or any article?

Comment: http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/safebrowsing/

Comment: is there any ready-made code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to your comment: This is not a code repository. You'll need to do your own development.

Back to your question: I would like to warn you that you will be exposing your API key to the general public when using javascript (as it's a client-side technology). Furthermore, you're opening the door to abusers. In the end, your "secret" API key might get suspended by Google quicker than you think.

In short: it could be done using the GET request examples the API documentation provides, but if I were you, I would think twice if javascript is really the best option you have.